# About eigenvectors, eigenvalues, and Representation Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $T:V \to V$ be a linear transformation.

Assume $\dim V=3$.

If $T$ has $3$ different eigenvalues, for instance $1,2,3$, then can I say that there exists a basis for $V$ such that $$[T]_B=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0  &0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 3
\end{bmatrix}$$

Moreover, if $V= \Bbb R^3$, then can I say that for any $\Bbb v \in V~~$, $~~T\Bbb v=A\Bbb v$ while $A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0  &0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 3
\end{bmatrix}$ ?

I'd like to hear some explanation about this, because I'm afraid that I am missing some crucial points here.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is important to distinguish the abstract transformation and vectors from their representation in a particular basis, so strictly speaking you cannot write $Tv=Av$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, $T$ may not have a diagonal form, but we can guarantee there exists a *Jordan basis* for $V$ such that $T$ can be written in [Jordan Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form). This looks very much like your matrix $A$, just with some ones on the super diagonal. Since $T$’s eigenvalues are all distinct, $T$ is guaranteed to be diagonalisable, with thanks to Miguel’s comment.

The matrix representation tends to assume the canonical basis vectors (columns of an identity matrix). Under the change of basis, the vectors that are written like that (e.g. $(0,1,0,0)$) are the eigenvectors of $T$. Then $A$ maps each eigenbasis vector to the relevant eigenvalue multiple, and sums together in a linear combination to produce the correct answer.

The typical notation for a diagonalisation of some $X$ into diagonal $D$ is this: $X=PDP^{-1}$ where $P$ is the change of basis matrix from the basis that $D$ takes to the basis that $X$ takes. We can rearrange: $XP=PD$. This means that $\forall v\in V$, $XPv=PDv$. Then the LHS is saying: we force $v$ into the basis of $X$ ($Pv$) and multiply by $X$ ($X$’s action on its basis). The RHS is saying: we take $D$’s action on some $v$ and then remap it into $X$’s basis so that the LHS and the RHS is the same. This is why $X$ and $D$ would be called *similar*: it’s the same action, just with two different bases in mind.

In your case, $Tv=Av$ only loosely speaking, because the LHS and the RHS are in different bases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I didn't learn Jordan form, so I only understand your second part of the answer, which confirms that my second part of the question is true, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Key points: let $v$ be written in terms of the canonical basis (whichever one $T$ was written in originally). Then let $Tv=k$, also written in that same basis. Now let’s remap $v\to u$, so that $u$ is $v$ in the eigenbasis (the basis that $T$ can be diagonal in). Then $Au=\hat k$ and $\hat k$, if written in terms of $T$’s basis, is exactly equal to $k$. So $Tv=Av$ if you are happy with the LHS and RHS being in different bases. What’s important is that $T$’s action on $V$ (under the canonical basis) is the same as $A$’s action on $V$ (under the eigenbasis). @CalculusLover

Comment: If the eigenvalues are different then the transformation is always diagonalizable. A Jordan block (with dimension greater than one) requires repeated eigenvalues.

Comment: @CalculusLover I’ve edited a further explanation

Comment: @Miguel good catch, I’ve edited that in

Answer (score 0):

Lets work in $\mathbb R^2$ to simplify things a little bit.  And, lets think about our transformation geometrically.

Most linear transformations can be thought of as some combination of dilations / compressions, rotations, and reflections.

Suppose $T$ is a matrix with positive real eigenvalues.

The eigenvectors indicate the direction of dilation, and the eigenvalues indicate the magnitude.  If we think about the the unit circle, and how the $T$ affects this set of points we get an image like this.

[image]

Once we have some familiarity with what $T$ does to the unit circle we can try some other shapes.

If we have a negative eigenvalue, we have a reflection.
If we have two, we have a double reflection (which is a rotation of 180 degrees).
If we have complex eigenvalues, they imply a rotation.

Not every matrix is diagonalizable, which means we have some transformation that cannot be described as a rotation, reflection or dilation, for example a shear.

More abstractly, it often convenient to change our basis, such that our transformation becomes as easy to work with as we can make it.  If possible we would like to work with a diagonal matrix, but if we cannot we work with a matrix in Jordan-Normal form.  All transformation will have some set of vectors whose direction is unchanged by the transformation.  These are the eigenvectors.  If we have as many eigenvectors as the dimension of our transformation, the transformation is diagonalizable.  Choosing these vectors as our basis, our transformation matrix becomes a diagonal matrix in the new basis.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer!